# Lua проблемы с юникодом

Tags: unicode, lua

Вопрос вот в чем. Lua написан на ANSI C и, как следствие не дружит с юникодом. Есть ли способ подружить их? Причем так, что бы работали стандартные функции для обработки строк и можно было бы передать строки в функцию на С++. Думал отводить на символ два байта, но тут проблемы со стандартными функциями. Еще думал кодировать юникодовские символы через \u002e, но тут те же проблемы, хотя регулярки должны работать. Хотелось бы обойтись минимальными затратами... Может, стоит использовать другой встраиваемый язык, но тогда там нужны регулярки и юникодовские строки, еще нужна возможность вызова функций из основной программы. И чем меньше размер, тем лучше (размер, можно сказать, критичен). Смотрел в сторону питона, но он очень уж всеобемлющий для скриптовика, да и таскать с собою два метра длл как-то не хочу

Answer (score 1):

Lua-строки могут содержать любые последовательности байт, так что можно использовать UTF-8. Для этого существует несколько библиотек.

Одна из наиболее простых и компактных - библиотека Selene Unicode. Эта библиотека, с двумя исправлениями серьёзных багов, входит в состав LuaFAR - библиотеки для написания плагинов и скриптов для FAR Manager.

Сам плагин пишется на C (фактически используется заготовка из состава LuaFAR), остальное на Lua. Пример: LuaFAR for Editor.

Comment: > для написания плагинов

Это вы загнули, подключаемые модули для фара нельзя написать на lua

Comment: Вообще-то я не написал, что (весь) плагин пишется на Lua.